# Unable to add to the rustc-link-search path of a dependency

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to build a test app using [cassandra-rs](https://github.com/tupshin/cassandra-rs) which uses the [DataStax CPP driver](https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver/). I am using `cargo 0.6.0 (ec9398e 2015-09-29) (built from git)`.

My DataStax driver is not located in the standard directories Cargo looks in.

I added a build script specifying the path to the DataStax driver:

```
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search={}", "/path/to/dir/");
}
```

Here is my Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "castest"
version = "0.1.0"
build = "build.rs"

[dependencies]
cassandra="*"
```

But `cargo build --verbose` shows that the additional search directory is not included when building.

The package that the build is actually failing on is cql_bindgen which is a dependency of cassandra-rs. In that project there is this build.rs:

```
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rustc-flags=-l dylib=crypto");
    println!("cargo:rustc-flags=-l dylib=ssl");
    println!("cargo:rustc-flags=-l dylib=stdc++");
    println!("cargo:rustc-flags=-l dylib=uv");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search={}", "/usr/lib/");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search={}", "/usr/local/lib64");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=cassandra_static");
}
```

How can I add additional libraries or otherwise override configuration in my project that is set in dependent projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A downstream user of a crate cannot make changes to how that crate is compiled, other than by [features](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#the-[features]-section) that the crate exposes.

When linking to existing native libraries, the Cargo [build script](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html) is used to help find the appropriate libraries to link to.

The correct solution here is to fix the upstream crate (cql_bindgen) [build.rs](https://github.com/tupshin/cql-bindgen/blob/f902f34e727654debb438f34e28960268ee8cb68/build.rs) to allow end users to specify alternate paths to search within. One way of doing this is to use the [`option_env!`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.option_env!.html) macro, something like:

```
if let Some(datastax_dir) = option_env!("CQL_BINDGEN_DATASTAX_LIB_PATH") {
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search={}", datastax_dir);
}
```

Of course, you can [override the dependency](http://doc.crates.io/guide.html#overriding-dependencies) with a local version as you iterate to get a solution that works locally.

In the mean time, you can try installing your library in one of the hard-coded directories that are already searched.

Comment: Thank you. I made the change you suggested (and allowed a semi-colon separated list of paths), overrode the dependency using my modified version of cql-bindgen, and compilation completed successfully.

Comment: @DavidEagen great! I'd suggest submitting your changes back upstream so you don't have to maintain your own fork and so others can benefit from your changes.